# Corda node terminals not starting from runnodes (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, command-prompt, corda

After deploying nodes from command prompt, I start the nodes using runnodes command. The terminal says nodes have already been started but terminal for individual node won't open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly check that you don't have any zombie Java processes running from a previous session, since you're on Windows, just check via Task Manager.

Secondly, it may be the case the nodes are shutting down immediately for some reason. Check the log files in build\nodes{nodeName}\logs